# Integrating ODE's

Tags: differential-equations

I have:

$$
m\frac{dV_y}{dt}=-k\cdot V_y-mg
$$
where, $V_y$ is velocity in the $y$-direction.

I have the initial condition `Vy[0]=40 Sin[40 Degrees]` and `y[0]=0`.

$m$, $k$ and $g$ are constants.
I am trying to integrate this to get a function for velocity and position.

I am not sure how to use the `DSolve` function in this case.

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear[y, t, m, g]
eq = m*y''[t] == -k*y'[t] - m*g;
ic = {y'[0] == 40 Sin[40 Degree], y[0] == 0};
sol = y[t] /. First@DSolve[{eq, ic}, y[t], t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

```
Y = Extract[
     y /. DSolve[{m*y''[t] == -k*y'[t] - m*g, y[0] == 0, 
            y'[0] == 40 Sin[40*Pi/180]}, y, t]  [[1]], 2]
(*(E^(-((k t)/ m)) m (-g m + E^((k t)/m) g (m - k t) + 40 (-1 + E^((k t)/m)) k Sin[(2 Pi])/9]))/k^2*)

Vy = D[Y,t] // FullSimplify
(*(-g m+E^(-((k t)/m)) (g m+40 k Sin[(2 Pi)/9]))/k*)
```